# Set limit to the number of recursive calls - Java

Tags: java, recursion, red-black-tree

I have a class of a Red-Black Tree.

I want to print it in-order (so the numbers would be printed from smallest to laregst).

Here's the printing method:

```
public void printTreeInOrder(Node node){
        //in-order printing (sorted)
        if (!(isNull(node))){
            printTreeInOrder((node.getLeft()));
            System.out.println(node.getValue());
            printTreeInOrder(node.getRight());
        }
    }
```

**However I want to print only the k smallest numbers**. It would be easy if I could limit the number of recursive calls, such as holding a sentinal and count the number of times the method is called.

But how do I it in a recursive function?

**I thought** of making a global variable k and count it in the function, but it doesn't sound right, **and k is a variable itself, it is not constant**.
I there a way I could count the amount of numbers printed in a recursive function?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: I know it does not answer the question... but in practice the iterative version of this kind of recursion tend to perform better and some stuff like early stops are slightly more straight forward (eg. ```if (--k == 0) return;```). For this kind of traversal you would need a ```Stack<Pair<Node,Action>>``` where Action  is an ```enum Action { GO_LEFT, PRINT, GO_RIGHT}```

Comment: It  seems that on one hand you want to limit the depth of the traversal and at the same time you want bottom k number .... do you actually mean to say that you want to limit the number of numbers to print (k)? You cannot limit the depth of the traversal if you hope to always get the smallest number. Please correct you question

Comment: @ValentinRuano I actually don't know what you mean. I want to print only k numbers out of the n in the tree, and do it sorted - inorder. I can't see the contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method returns the number of elements remaining to be printed and accepts the maximum number of elements that can be printed from this node.

```
public int printTreeInOrder(Node node, int k){
    //in-order printing (sorted)
    if (k>0 && !(isNull(node))){
        k = printTreeInOrder(node.getLeft(),k);
        if (k>0) {
            System.out.println(node.getValue());
            k--;
        }
        return printTreeInOrder(node.getRight(),k);
    }
    return k;
}
```